# Java match on one regex decimal place

Tags: java, regex, if-statement

Im trying to get to grips with the regex syntax.  Does anyone know how I can make the following work?

```
    // if there is already a decimal place in the string ignore
    String origString = txtDisplay.getText();

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("/\\./");

    //pattern = 
    if(pattern.matcher(origString)){
        System.out.println("DEBUG - HAS A DECIMAL IGNORE");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("DEBUG - No Decimal");
    }
```

Comment: thanks for feedback.  I will keep trying.  I am new to java so im trying to learn how to do both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java regular expressions don't need pattern delimiters; i.e. they don't need the `/` and `/` slashes at the start and end of the pattern or they will be interpreted literally.

You need to change your pattern to:

```
\\.
```

and then you can you can check if there is a match like this:

```
Matcher matcher = pattern.marcher(origString);
if(matcher.find()){
    System.out.println("DEBUG - HAS A DECIMAL IGNORE");
}
else{
    System.out.println("DEBUG - No Decimal");
}
```

but in case you want to check if a string contains a dot or any other string literal you can just use:

```
bool doesItContain = origString.indexOf('.') != -1;
```

where [`indexOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String%29) takes as a parameter any string.

Comment: It does not create the Matcher object.  My IDE highlights it as red saying cannot find symbol?  any idea what that means?  Do i need o import something for it to work?

Comment: @Robbo_UK Ah Yes. You need to import `import java.util.regex.*`;